# appending rows to an existing data list in angular

Tags: json, html, angular, typescript

I'm displaying data from a back-end system. The data comes from a table that is for a window of time receiving new rows. I have a mechanism to fetch those rows within an angular timer. My question, given the template below, how can i add those new rows to my list as shown below without redrawing the entire list.

```
template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
  <p>Heroes:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      {{ hero }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using angular 2+ version, you need not worry about the redrawing list part as it will handle it automatically using shadow DOM.

Comment: Great, this is the answer i was looking for. I will try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you looked the obserbvables from rxjs?

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

they can provide a variable that automaticaly updates with the new value provided

Comment: i use a timer for this. I was more thinking of the UI part. When my timer ticks, i will call a service and get new rows. I want to append the new rows to my data list without redrawing the entire list. Not sure how observable will help here

Comment: as sayed `Shubham Agrawal` in fact you got nothing to do, i just done a try, your code works perfectly